# NLembedding for iOS returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, nlp

I'm currently implementing on-device vector search using Apple's Natural Language Library. However, I'm facing an issue where the iOS SentenceEmbedding function is returning nil. It was working fine on macOS and iOS until recently.

I've attached the terminal output and the code line where the error occurs.

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Error line:

```
let embedding = NLEmbedding.sentenceEmbedding(for: .english)!
```

Error:

```
2023-07-14 18:33:29.776152+0530 pdfembedding[3323:124750] Unable to locate Asset for sentence embedding model for local en.

pdfembedding/VectorEmbedding.swift:69: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

2023-07-14 18:33:29.776391+0530 pdfembedding[3323:124750] pdfembedding/VectorEmbedding.swift:69: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/672465 could be a bug related to some iOS versions?

Comment: I get this with MacOS 14.2.1 with Swift Playgrounds.